# Deletion using recursion

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have the following tree-like structure made out of nested dictionaries. Every dictionary has a tuple as a key and contains a list of dictionaries. The list can be empty.

```
 {(0, 26): [{(2, 9): [{(4, 7): []},
                {(6, 9): []},
                 {(2, 5): []},
                 {(5, 8): []},
                 {(3, 6): []},
                 {(2, 7): [{(4, 7): []}, {(2, 5): []}, {(3, 6): []}]},
                 {(3, 8): [{(4, 7): []}, {(5, 8): []}, {(3, 6): []}]}]},
            {(14, 27): [{(14, 17): []},
                  {(17, 20): []},
                  {(18, 21): []},
                  {(20, 23): []},
                  {(22, 25): []},
                   {(17, 21): [{(17, 20): []}, {(18, 21): []}]}]},
            {(8, 16): [{(12, 16): []},
                  {(8, 11): []},
                  {(10, 16): [{(12, 16): []}]},
                  {(9, 12): []}]},
            {(7, 14): [{(7, 12): [{(7, 10): []},
                             {(8, 11): []},
                             {(9, 12): []}]},
                  {(7, 10): []},
                  {(8, 11): []},
                  {(9, 12): []}]},
            {(1, 4): []}]}
```

I am trying to delete dictionaries that may be contained within other dictionaries. If a dictionary at 'depth d' has a list with a dictionary that has a key found at 'depth d-1' I would want the routine to delete the dictionary at 'depth d-1'.
For instance, the dictionary with key (2,9) contains a dictionary with key (4,7). This dictionary is actually contained in two other dictionaries within the same dictionary with keys (2,7) and (3,8). I would like to write a routine in order to obtain the following result ... here I am just showing the result for dictionary with key (2,9):

```
{(2, 9): [{(6, 9): []},
    {(2, 7): [{(4, 7): []}, {(2, 5): []}, {(3, 6): []}]},
    {(3, 8): [{(4, 7): []}, {(5, 8): []}, {(3, 6): []}]}]},
```

I am thinking that I should be able to do this using recursion but I have not been successful.Can this be resolved through recursion? If not, what would be the better way of solving it?

Comment: So, does the contents of the list matter? Or are you just deleting by key? Also, just to confirm, if an entry is a depth d, then all entries of depth d - 1 and lesser are to be deleted?

Comment: Could you tell use what exactly you want to do? It's not clear what your routines needs to do.

Comment: The lists can contain other dictionaries. If a list contains a dictionary with a key that is found at depth d-1 then we would want the entry at depth d-1 to be deleted (but not the one at depth d). Yes, on your last question.

Comment: @marcos: So if I have  `(4, 5): []` at depth `d`, and  `(4, 5) : [..... ] # non-empty` at depth `d - 1`, does this get deleted?

Comment: Good question! Only the opposite can happen. That is, that I have at depth d-1 (4,5):[ ] and at depth d (4,5):[.....] #non-empty

Comment: Yeah, I don't think recursion is the right fit for this. You want to delete after comparing elements which have no hierarchical relationship at all. In your example, the dicts with keys (4, 7) are not in the same line of ancestry. That makes things every difficult. Is changing your data representation an option?

Comment: @Coldspeed I was fearful about that. I am not certain I can change the data representation. Indeed, it is only once the data is in this format that one can tell which should be eliminated. This is part of a larger problem.

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying it is impossible. Just that it is very challenging, and not something you should expect others to solve for you. I suggest you take your own time and figure out a good approach to this problem. I wish you the very best.

Comment: Are you able to explain what this data structure is or what you're trying to achieve with this? It feels like an overly-complicated tree that could be done some other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Build a dict key:list of index
for i, d in enumerate(list_of_dict):
    key = d.keys()[0]
    if not key in dict_idx:
        dict_idx[key] = []
    dict_idx[key]. append(i)

# Delete from all multiple key the first 
for key in dict_idx:
    if len(dict_idx[key]) > 1:
        del list_of_dict[dict_idx[key][0]]
```